# Send Function key with xvkbd

Tags: bash, keyboard

How can I send a function key (like F11) with xvkbd?
I cannot find anything on the internet and the man page only shows keys like Control or ALT.  I know the command will start with
`xvkbd -xsendevent -string ...`, but I don't know how to complete it.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I never used xvkbd but it accepts keysym as input values according to the manpage. Within your X11/xorg session, start `xev`, then press F11 to get the associated keysym value.